# Proof of $ \sqrt{2}|z|\geq|Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove  $\sqrt{2}|z|\geq|Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$

---

This is what I tried to do :

$Let$ $z=x+iy$ , this gives us $|Re(z)| = |x|$ and $|Im(z)|=|y|$

Also , $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Then we have $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \geq x +y $

$\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2} \geq x +y$

$\Rightarrow$ $2x^2+2y^2 \geq (x +y)^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $2x^2+2y^2 \geq x^2 +2xy +y^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy $

---

Is this correct so far ? How do I proceed from here ?

Comment: Hint: square both sides of your inequality and prove this instead.

Comment: You could also write it as $$\frac{|x|+|y|}2\le\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}2}$$ which is the most simple case of the inequality between the arithmetic and quadratic mean, and a direct consequence of the fact that the square function is convex (and monotone on positive arguments), as for any convex function you get $f(\frac{x+y}2)\le\frac{f(x)+f(y)}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \geq |x| +|y| $$

But if you write  $a= |x|$ and $b= |y|$ then $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \geq a +b $$

and the proof goes as you did.

Comment: Why is it important to let $a=|x|$ and $b=|y|$ ?

Comment: You can not square something which is not positive on both side. Say $1>-2$ but if you square it you get $1>4$ which is not true. Any way notation $a,b$ just make it easier, since $x^2 =|x|^2 = a^2$

Comment: Ok , makes sense. Can I leave my proof as is , or should I complete it as J. G. answered?

Comment: As a question it is OK, you don't have to change it.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Further to greedoid's answer, you really should use $\Leftarrow$ or $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ because we want to show that $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, a corollary of $(a-b)^2\ge 0$, implies the desired result $\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}\ge a+b$.

Comment: So I could do the following $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \ge 0$ which will give me $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$

Comment: @Kenneth The correct way to think about it is that $(a-b)^2\ge 0\implies 2(a^2+b^2)\ge (a+b)^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the help.